# Issues with MongoDB install on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ubuntu-8.04, mongodb

I am installing MongoDB (1.4.1) on Ubuntu (8.04 LTS) and I continuously have a problem where I can be in /usr/local/mongodb/bin and run ./mongo or ./mongod and I am returned "No such file or directory."

Let me be very clear here... the files ARE there!

The obvious go-to solution is that it is because of permission issues but the permissions are fine. I've even tried others out, still without any luck.

I'm really at the end here and any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just going out on a limb here, if you're running the 64bit version of Ubuntu, and the installers need the 32bit libraries, you'll run into this issue.  Try running ldd against the files you're trying to run and see if any of the libraries are missing.

Comment: Didn't realize you posted this answer. I posted my answer below. Works great now!

Comment: The first time this happened to me was with vendor software which only came in one version, they didn't specify 32bit libraries in their docs as a requirement, and I forgot that Ubuntu only installs 64bit libs by default on a 64bit machine.  I was *Sooooooo* pissed the day I figured this one out.  Never again I said...

Answer (score 1):

Ready for a good laugh...

I accidentally downloaded the 32-bit version and installed it on 64-bit hardware.

The 64-bit version works like a charm.

Thanks anyway!